# How to store the drop value as a new data in my array?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have drop function and i want to store the value as a new data in my array, is it possible?

```
    series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                type: 'spline',
                connectNulls: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                data: [13, 54, 35, 24, 65, 81,13, 54, 35, 24, 65, 81,13, 54, 35, 24, 65, 81],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' °C',
                },
                point: {
            events: {
            drag: function() {
              document.getElementById('point-temp').value = (Math.round(this.y));
            }
          }
        },
            }]


This is how I show it in an input field :

    <input placeholder="new Temperature" id="point-temp" type="text" class="field"  value="">

This is the button to store the new point value in my array.

     <button class="btn"  id="save-data">Save to data</button>
```

and this is the function to add the new data to the array but it's not working

```
document.getElementById('save-data').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('point-temp').value;
    chart.series[0].data(point);
});
```

Comment: Hi @A.Bar, Could you describe more precisely what you want to achieve? Your code seems to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ox9hz2dk/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, i have this drop value in an input field now but what i want is to store this value in my data once i click in button save for ex, and thanks for helping !!

Comment: Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kxh5mngp/, you can see that your value is already saved in the data.

Comment: Make sure you explain yourself in the question you have posted

Comment: @Sanip i've explaned more !!

Comment: @Sanip but i guess i need a function to store the new data in the array, othewise how to do thias  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `click` event to the 'save' button and store a value from the input in the correct place in a data array:

```
var data = [10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20],
    newData = data.slice();

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        animation: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    drop: function() {
                        var inputEl = document.getElementById('point-temp');
                        inputEl.value = this.y;
                        inputEl['data-index'] = this.index;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    series: [{
        data: data,
        draggableY: true
    }]
});


document.getElementById('save-data')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
        var inputEl = document.getElementById('point-temp');
        newData[inputEl['data-index']] = Math.round(Number(inputEl.value));
    });
```

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3m04f9dz/

**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.drop

Comment: @ppotaczeck it works, i could see the change when i console log the array but it wont store it when i refresh the page, i dunno if this is possible to do ?

Comment: @A.Bar, You would have to store the variable for example in `localStorage`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4soguvrk/

Comment: @ppotaczeck so its not working to store directly to our array in this case ?

Comment: @A.Bar, What do you mean? What array do you ask about? Do you want to present the saved data directly on the chart? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z7rqv4uc/

Comment: @ppotaczeck now i got what you mean, i'm totally new in this things, thanks alot for your help :)